# how can i track existing number of objects of a given class without introducing a non-class member variable in php?

Tags: php, class, static, constructor, tags

i get some collection of solutions please help me to find correct one.

-> add member variable increment in default constructor and decrement in destructor.

-> add local variable that goes incremented in each constructor and decremented in destructor.

-> add static member variable that get incremented in each constructor and decremented in the destructor.

-> cannot be accomplished since the creation of the objects is being done dynamically via "new".

these are my four points please select me the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a static member variable:

```
class foo {
    protected static $instances = 0;

    public function __construct() {
        self::$instances++;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        self::$instances--;
    }
}
```

But remember that you can create new instances without hitting the constructor (namely via [`clone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php), [`__set_state()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.set-state) (which is used by `var_export`) and [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep) )...  So you'll need to add:

```
public function __clone() {
    self::$instances++;
}

public function __wakeup() {
    self::$instances++;
}

public static function __set_state($data) {
    $obj = new self();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $obj->$key = $value;
    }
    return $value;
}
```